# jQuery: responsive vertical ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using this plugin: http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/ to create a vertical news ticker. Great plugin too, works great, small problem though, as you can see via my fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vzb4mv0n/3/ if the heights of the `li` elements vary in size, this leaves large gaps in between each element, as it seems the plugin takes the `li` element with the largest height, and assigns this to all `li` elements, which doesn't look great as I'd like them to all sit flush against each other, regardless of how many lines are in the copy, or the window size etc etc. 
Other than my fiddle link about, all find the neccessary code below too:
HTML

```
<div id="example">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</li>
        <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut</li>
        <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</li>
        <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut</li>
        <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</li>
        <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut</li>
        <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').vTicker('init', {
        speed: 600,
        pause: 2000
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    Resize();
});

//Every resize of window
$(window).resize(function () {
    Resize();
});

//Dynamically assign height
function Resize() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        finalHeight = windowHeight + 'px';

    $('#example').css('height', finalHeight);

}
```

CSS

```
#example {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #345c6d;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#example li {
    font-size: 50px;
}
#example li:after {
    content:">";
    display: block;
}
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to play with the following options of the ticker plugin to change that behavior.

```
$('#example').vTicker('init', {
    speed: 600,
    pause: 2000,
    showItems: 3,
    height: 200
});
```

`showItems`and `height` are what you're looking for.
You can read more about the options right [here](http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/methods/).

http://jsfiddle.net/spLt312e/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use window.resize but @media quires in css to make it happen.

For example if you want to change your font-size and you have this:

```
#example li {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Then you can to this to change it for a specific view:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #example li {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

Or any other style rule you'd love.

resize window with JS could produce perfomance issues to user's browser.